# It is different between google analytics page data and api response

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have attached google analytics page data. The below is api response.
They looks different between them and I can't get the correct data.
Who knows about this problem?

[image]

```
ga:bounces: "304"
ga:organicSearches: "69"
ga:pageviews: "8012"
ga:socialInteractionsPerSession: "0.0"
ga:uniquePageviews: "4461"
```

Comment: Make sure the dates are exactly the same.  And all of the dimensions and metrics are the same.

Comment: @DalmTo, I have set the same dates range and on api and google analytics page.
As you can see, is it possible to get bouces value as "304%"?
I think, 100% is the maxim value, isn't it?

Comment: my guess is you are not requesting all of the dimensions and metrics in the report you are looking at from the api.  which report is that

Comment: The metrics on the screenshot and in the API response are all different, so they cannot be compared like this. ga:bounces is the number of bounced sessions. Bounce rate is the number of bounced sessions divided by number of all sessions.